# Tools for "bound guessing"

Tags: symbolic-computation, mathematical-software

I have a somewhat complicated symbolic expression of the form $\frac{J-a+\frac{q}{a}}{J(J-a)+q}$, where $J,a$ and $q$ are themselves affine functions of four other variables $d,r,c,s$, and I want to find some tame upper bound for the expression in terms of $d,r,c,s$. Sometimes this works well by simplifying the original expression with the use of a symbolic math package (I use MATLAB) and staring at the result for long enough, but this time it didn't.

So, I wonder: is there some automatic tool that helps with this kind of problem? Maybe something similar to [AutoGraphiX](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571065305801519)?

Comment: That you have it in such a form is perhaps the best tool.  Graph the expression in J, a and q to see where it potentially blows up, and then see if that relation occurs and is nicely representable in terms of your four favorite variables.  My guess is that a close to 0 requires attention as does a close to (q/J + J).  Gerhard "Ask Me About Blowing Up" Paseman, 2012.12.11